# How to remove the restriction of output information using pagination?

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I use Ngx-pagination. And the amount of data is displayed as much as I set in "totalItems". That is, if I specify more data than there are in JSON, then extra empty pages are added. And this is not good. How to do this, automatically determine the amount of data that  want to display in the pagination?

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:page, id: 'server', totalItems: total}"> 
....
</div>
<div class="pagination-block " style="justify-content: center">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPosts($event)" id="server">
  </pagination-controls>
</div>
```

ts:

```
 page: number;
  total: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts(this.page);
  }

  getPosts(page: number) {
    this.page = page;
    this.total = 3256;
    this.servPost.getPosts(page).subscribe(
      posts => this.posts = posts
    );
  }
```

Comment: What, no one knows how this can be implemented more correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As per the ngx-pagination documentation, Your get array with array length, should have something like this :

```
Use this :
{
  count: 14453,
  data: [
    { /* item 1 */ },
    { /* item 2 */ },
    { /* item 3 */ },
    { /*   ...  */ },
    { /* item 10 */ }
  ]
}

Instead of :
posts: [
  { /* item 1 */ },
  { /* item 2 */ },
  { /* item 3 */ },
  { /*   ...  */ },
  { /* item 10 */ }
]
```

and your typescript will have something like this :

```
 getPosts(page: number) {
    this.page = page;
    // this.total = 3256;
    this.servPost.getPosts(page).subscribe(
      posts => this.posts = posts
    );
  }
```

Then use this in your html like this :

```
*ngFor="let item of posts?.data | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page, totalItems: posts?.count }"
```

Reference link : https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination  #Server-Side Paging

Comment: Here is the demo of server side pagination using ngx-pagination : http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging

Comment: Tried to do so, but the pages are not displayed at all

Comment: had you check the demo from above shared link?

Comment: and don't forgot to pass page number on page Initialization.  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts(1);
  }

Comment: Damn, I just got confused, I can't get something

Comment: post?.count ?? maybe post?.length

Comment: No he get only 10 records every time So we can not use posts?.length. We need to display total number of records available in database. That why we get total number of records from server side inside "count" variable, and we can use it in our html totalItem.

Comment: @user10254427 can you please create stackblitz demo for that, So after that i will modify it